# Chrome ignores NPAPI event listener only when created dynamically

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, vlc, npapi

Using javascript to create the "VLC web plugin" embed tag:

```
function main() {
    var vlc = document.createElement('embed');
    vlc.setAttribute('type','application/x-vlc-plugin');
    vlc.setAttribute('target','file:///pilot.mp4');
    vlc.addEventListener('MediaPlayerPlaying', function() {
        alert('playing');
    }, false);
    document.body.appendChild(vlc);
}
```

With Chrome (32.0.1700.77) the video plays but the event is not fired.

If I use html to create the embed, the event is fired

It works perfectly with Firefox

Answer (score 0):

The event listener must be registered after the appendChild. Is this canonical?. I really want to catch the first 'play' event but this is another question